# Mockito error with method POST,when using @Mock?

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, junit4

I have a simple annotated controller similar to this one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/search" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchForm(@Valid Account account, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //do something

    return "app";
}
```

and I want to test it with an unit test like this:

```
private List<Account> listAccount = new ArrayList<Account>();
@Before
public void prepairUp() {

    // //// // ===============SETUP FOR MOCK========================
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
}
@Test
public void tesControllerSearchForm() throws Exception {

    ModelMap modelMap = mock(ModelMap.class);

    Account account = mock(Account.class);
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    final String review = accountController.searchForm(account, modelMap , request);

    when(accountService.findAllAccount()).thenReturn(listAccount);


    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/search")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("listAccounts", listAccount))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name(review));


}
```

it not work, not fail, not true, error line

```
final String review = accountController.searchForm(account, model, request);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are mocking the controller you have to manually set the beans which are normally injected by spring into the controller. That's why a NullPointer is thrown in your Controller.

Modify your prepairUp the following:

```
[Some Annotations you already have...]
public class ControllerTest {

    @Inject
    private AccountService accountService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void prepairUp() {

        // //// // ===============SETUP FOR MOCK========================
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        AccountController accountController = new AccountController();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountController, "accountService", accountService);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void tesControllerSearchForm() {
        ...
    }

    ....
}
```

You only need to setup once, so just change your @Before to @PostConstruct.

Comment: i have 
` @InjectMocks
 private AccountController accountController;

 @Mock
 //@InjectMocks
 private AccountService accountService;

 @Mock
 private AccountDao accountDao;

 @Mock
 private Account account;`

Comment: Thats okay - but you need to set them with ReflectionTestUtils either. Of course you need to mock your method calls as well, otherwise next Exception is thrown